# NoMethodError at adding redirection to routes.rb on Refinery CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I added to routes.rb due to redirecting to new path from old path:

```
Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  get 'about.html', to: redirect('/about')
end

mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: '/'
```

As a result, it was not redirected to '/about' and raise NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `valid_encoding?' for :en:Symbol:
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:23:in `block in call'
```

actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:23:

```
req.symbolized_path_parameters.each do |key, value|
  unless value.valid_encoding? # <= L23
    raise ActionController::BadRequest, "Invalid parameter: #{key} => #{value}"
  end
end
```

when opened 'localhost:3000/about.html'

using gems: refinerycms 3.0.0, rails 4.1.9

Any idea for solving this problem?

Comment: Can you post the controller code for the about page ?

Comment: And why are you opening /about.html instead of /about

Comment: @Daisuke Terada - having exact same issue with Refinery and redirecting 404s. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@asgeo1 Finally I found another solution. My solution is that creating static pages by [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage).
I guess in this case could not keep up both the redirection and dynamic routing by Refinery::Pages.

- Stop mounting RefineryCMS on root and mount on '/cms'
- Create /app/views/pages/about.html.erb, so that is published as '/about'. ref: [high_voltage:Usage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#usage)

following the routes.rb:

```
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: '/cms'
  get 'about.html', to: redirect('/about')
```

if you need also managing the page by Refinery::Pages, create '/about' page on RefineryCMS,

following the app/views/pages/about.html.erb:

```
<% @page = Refinery::Pages.find_by(link_url: '/about') %>
<%= raw @page.content_for(:body) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted , you are missing one thing and that's the controller code . Try the following in the about_controller.rb .

```
def find_page
    @page = ::Refinery::Page.find_by_link_url("/about")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The about page was created as a record of Refinery::Page.
I expect that opening /about.html will redirect to /about.

Refinery::Page.find_by_link_url("/about")
is not found.

:link_url was blank in the about page.

The about page:

`
- Created on Refinery CMS /admin/pages  
- and inputed 'about' to :title  
- publshed as url "http://localhost:3000/about"
`